# ERROR ITMS-90596: "Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at Payload"

Tags: ios, xcode, application-loader

I am Using xCode 8.0 and build an ipa for my project and uploading it using Application Loader but i am getting an error please see below screen shot:

[image]

I have successfully uploaded one of prior version of same application few minutes before but now i am getting the above error without any changes.

Thanks in Advance...!!

Comment: If there is any file named in your assets **car** check it is not corrupted.

Comment: No there is no any assets named Car. I have uploaded it using xcode it is successfully uploaded.

Comment: Great. Then it should be an issue of different application loader.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"I had two Xcodes on my Mac, Xcode 7.3 and 8.1. I made the archive using 8.1 but was uploading it with Xcode 7.3's Application Loader (3.5). Uploading with Xcode 8.1's Application Loader (3.6) resolved the issue for me".

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63321

Comment: agree but the thing is few minutes before I have uploaded it successfully using same Xcode and application loader.

Comment: did you check the Application Loader version while uploading in both case.possibly error may occur due to this.

Comment: I have uploaded it using xcode it is successfully uploaded.

Comment: Ran into the same issue and had to set the command line tools to the right version.

Answer (score 2):

Got this error when trying to upload Xcode 11 built ipa with old Application Loader.

But from Xcode 11 Application Loader is no longer included with Xcode.

When tried with the latest app submission approach using Transporter (https://apps.apple.com/in/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12), submission was successful.

Good Luck!

Comment: In our case we have some apps being built with Xcode 10 and others with Xcode 11. Trying to upload a Xcode 11 built app with Application Loader throws this error.

Answer (score 1):

I got the following when using Application Loader 3.7.1

[image]

I updated to 3.7.2 and it fixed the problem. So you may want to also make sure there's no new XCode versions.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. I fix it by uploading app using Xcode Organizer. Archive app and upload to app tore using Organizer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue with XCode 8.3.2.
During upload process there was a checkmark on "Rebuild with Bitcode". After I remove it - the build was successfully uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I used old Application Loader and saw this error. To launch latest Application Loader chose Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader